# Dart - HTTP status code 200 but response body is null

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I'm new to Dart and I'm learning about fetching data from the Internet. I'm using https://picsum.photos/ for practice and below is part of the code.

```dart
String picture;

class GalleryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GalleryPageState createState() => _GalleryPageState();
}

class _GalleryPageState extends State<GalleryPage> {
  Future<String> fetchPictures() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://picsum.photos/id/0/info');

    if (response.statusCode == 200)
      return picture = response.body;
    else
      throw Exception('Failed to load pictures');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(pictures);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I tried to send the request in an http file in VSCode and below was part of the response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2020 02:23:57 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Content-Encoding: gzip

{
  "id": "0",
  "author": "Alejandro Escamilla",
  "width": 5616,
  "height": 3744,
  "url": "https://unsplash.com/photos/yC-Yzbqy7PY",
  "download_url": "https://picsum.photos/id/0/5616/3744"
}
```

However, the result of the print statement is null and I have no idea why this is the case. Could anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling `fetchPictures`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the `picture` string in your state and then call `fetchPictures()` in `initState`.

```dart
class GalleryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GalleryPageState createState() => _GalleryPageState();
}

class _GalleryPageState extends State<GalleryPage> {
  String picture;

  Future<String> fetchPictures() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://picsum.photos/id/0/info');

    if (response.statusCode == 200)
      picture = response.body;
      print(picture); // print here
      setState(() {});
    else
      throw Exception('Failed to load pictures');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchPictures();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return picture == null
             ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
             : Text(picture);
  }
}
```